# Call a function that is in a file? my.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, function-call

Writing my first bash function, trying to execute it from shell, the contents of the file look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
myFirstFunction(){
curl --url "$1" --output "$2" #;
ffmpeg --i "$2" -c:v "$3"; #$2 becomes the input and $3 becomes the new output.
rm "$2" #then I clean up by deleting $2.
}

#end
```

I give the script permission to run without my typing `bash`:

`chmod +x myfirstscript.sh`

And from shell I tried to fun the function like this:

`myfirstscript.sh myFirstFunction inputFN firstOutputFN lastOutputFN`

### My question:

As far as manuals and tutorials, I cannot find out how to call the function out of the file and pass all the arguments to the function.  Can you please show me how?

### Carriage Returns Update:

I had been getting this error:  `myfirstfunction.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token` $'{\r''`.  I fixed this by replacing \r\n with \n via notepad++.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your file probably has Windows-style CRLF line endings and the shell that's trying to execute it is expecting Unix-style LF line endings.

Comment: Install `dos2unix` in your WSL environment and run it on the file.

Comment: `$'\r'` is the bash denotation of a string consisting of a sole CR.

Comment: Yes, this rids the error, but there is still the main question "how do I call the function from shell".  I don't know how to call the function from the debian terminal.  I can't find documentation on how to call the function from the file with arguments.

Comment: If you run the script normally, it runs as a subprocess, and the function is only defined in that subprocess (and vanishes when the script finishes and the subprocess exits). You can use `source` or `.` to run the script in your shell (rather than a subprocess), and then just run `myFirstFunction firstarg secondarg etc`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes.  I did use `source scriptname.sh; functionName firstarg secondarg thirdarg`